# WordPress Kubernetes container performance issue

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have deployed stateless WordPress to Kubernetes with an official docker image which has an inbuilt apache.

The Kubernetes POD is running with Nginx ingress but the WordPress site performance is so poor.

Flow is something like : ingress > WordPress service > apache running inside a container and serve WordPress file.

I tried creating WordPress php-fpm image but Nginx-ingress is not changing backend protocol.

Nginx ingress issue : https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/458#issuecomment-675869805

Does anybody have experience with this and can suggest a better way to improve the performance of WordPress?

NOTE : WordPress is stateless and we are doing **rolling update** deployments so using **shared volume** might create issues.

One thought in mind create deployment with two container (One POD with two container nginx and Wordpress php-fpm) so flow will be something like : ingress-nginx > nginx container > Wordpress php-fpm container internally and file get serve.(But again share volume issue since we are doing rolling update)

Comment: have you been trying to troubleshoot it?  At least to profile it. Is PHP OPcache enabled?

Comment: sure i will try to look into thanks for suggestion